# sql server log shipping to remote server in different network

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, backup, disaster-recovery, log-shipping

I need to setup a Disaster Recovery. I need to setup Log shipping to remote server not in same network. I can transfer log shipping trc files to remote machine through internet. But how to import trc files to secondary server. Actually i am trying to logship to a remote server for backup copy of database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can restore the .trn files using [RESTORE LOG](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177446.aspx) (WITH NORECOVERY).

You need to do a full backup & restore (WITH NORECOVERY) of the database before you can restore any transaction logs.

If you can setup a VPN, it's best to let SQLServer do the whole backup & restore & verify - the copy phase is pretty easy to override - just write your own copy SQLAgent job & disable the copy job that SQL setup for you.